# How can I make the advanced button work in chrome 'App isnt verified'?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I'm sorry this question might not be completely on topic, but i couldn't find answers googling it.

I'm creating an google app script (with clasp).

When i run the script i get the following popup as usual:

[image]

I'm supposed to click on advance and go anways.

But the **advanced** button no longer works! it doesn't show me the followup button to continue anymore!

Does anyone have the same issue and was able to fix it? It seems to have originated after the chrome update (with rounded ui).

I tried deleting the original grant (i added a feature that needed bigger scope), but even that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be one of my chrome extensions.

Doing the same thing in **incognito mode**, worked!